# React Router: Determine if element is rendered within an Outlet or as direct route child

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React Project using **React Router v6**.

I use different routes for mobile and desktop in order to render fewer or more information depending on the screen size.

**Mobile `/site/id`:**
Renders only **Detailview**

**Desktop `/site/id`:**
Renders **Overview** on the *left* and **Detailview** on the *right*

**Mobile or Desktop `/site`:**
Renders only **Overview**

Therefore I use a code structure like

```
const sidebarContent = <Route path=':id' element={<Detail />}>;

return (
  <Routes basename="/site">
    <Route path='/' element={<Overview />}>
      {isDesktop ? sidebarContent : null}
    </Route>
    {! isDesktop ? sidebarContent : null}
  </Routes>
);
```

Whereas my Overview.js looks something like

```
return(<>
  <div> ... Overview Code ... </div>
  <Outlet/>
</>);
```

Now within my Detailview I would like to determine weather the Detailview is currently rendered as a standalone route element or as the `<Outlet/>` component within the Overview

Answer (score 1):

A trivial way for a component to "confirm" if it's rendered within an `Outlet` context or not is for the `Outlet` to provide a simple value and for the descendent component to use the `useOutletContext` hook to access the value. If the value exists then the descendent component is rendered within the `Outlet`, otherwise it is not.

Example:

```
const Overview = () => (
  <>
    <div> ... Overview Code ... </div>
    <Outlet context={true} />
  </>
);
```

```
const Detail = () => {
  const isInOutlet = useOutletContext();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Detail</h1>
      <div>Is is Outlet context: {JSON.stringify(!!isInOutlet)}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-determine-if-element-is-rendered-within-an-outlet-or-as-direct-rou]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is also the workaround I came up with. Though I was wondering if there would be a more straightforward solution for this without always having to provide a context.

Comment: @TimNikischin You could abstract the "providing a context value" into a custom `Outlet` component and hook pair, but no, I don't think there's a shorter "short cut" for this.